# GLGE, SceneJS or WebGLU for WebGL development?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm looking to do some development with WebGL, 
mostly for presentation and navigation purposes (like showing a house with possible navigation)

I want to know if anyone has experience with these libraries,  
which has the fastest learning curve, as well as a strong developing community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only have a little experience with [THREE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) by @mrdoob, although still in development it's easy to understand and there's a lot of activity going on in this project.
It has been a while since i used it so it might be more mature now.

Answer (score 0):

Something that you should be aware is that you will not be able to run GLGE depending projects without first creating a local server. On the other hand, project based on three.js can be ran by simply double clicking the html page.

Comment: yes, it's the main reason I started using three.js for some projects - just faster to get started